# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi not working

Tags: drivers, usb

using a Brostrend (Realtek) AC3L wifi usb adapter.  Driver is installed Successfully.

ls = shows the directory created
lsusb = bus 003 Device 005: ID )bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
lsmod = 88x2bu

```
dmesg | grep rtl88x2bu

 output =
 [    3.929094] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 485 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1704 
rtw_os_ndev_register+0x6c/0x151 [88x2bu]
[    3.947195] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 485 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3171 
rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xb6/0xde [88x2bu]
[    4.225207] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88x2bu
[   55.336731] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 138 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1704 
rtw_os_ndev_register+0x6c/0x151 [88x2bu]
[   55.350790] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 138 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3171 
rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xb6/0xde [88x2bu]
[   59.540195] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 155 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1704 
rtw_os_ndev_register+0x6c/0x151 [88x2bu]
[   59.558791] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 155 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3171 
rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xb6/0xde [88x2bu]
[  170.449271] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 144 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1704 
rtw_os_ndev_register+0x6c/0x151 [88x2bu]
[  170.466797] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 144 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3171 
rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xb6/0xde [88x2bu]
[  175.588367] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 155 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1704 
rtw_os_ndev_register+0x6c/0x151 [88x2bu]
[  175.602792] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 155 at 
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.6.1/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3171 
rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xb6/0xde [88x2bu]

lshw -C network

output
 *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 19
        bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
        logical name: eno1
        version: 04
        serial: 6c:3b:e5:0a:74:f4
        size: 1Gbit/s
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 
10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e 
driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.0.30 
latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
        resources: irq:25 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff 
memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

I hope this helps you to help find my problem